# I am making one coocs2d game and implementing Game Center in it. My Game Center isn't work with landscape mode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to change my game center default to landscape mode but no success. I have tried some classes but no result...

```
#import "GKMatchmakerViewController-LandscapeOnly.h"

@implementation GKMatchmakerViewController (LandscapeOnly)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
}

@end
```

This class is also implemented for my game.

Please let me help if you have some solutions.

Comment: @Yannick i think there is something while creating sandbox environment. I actually dont know but Apple should give this option in their framework or in sandbox environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey this thing is not working in simulator but it works fine for device for me......

solved issue....